# C++ pointer out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried looking for an answer but I couldn't find one. I'm new to C++ so pointers are not yet intuitive to me.

I have a program that has a `main` and other separate functions that are run when a button on the GUI is clicked.

When compiling I get an error from the clickbutton function which states the pointer is undeclared. I know it's a scope issue but I'm not sure how to deal with this. I know it's a very simple answer but I can't seem to find it online. Please let me know what is the proper way to access it.

```
int main () {
...
Contract contract;
contract.firstvalue = 1 // various variables that need to be set for this class
contract.secondvalue = 2 // various variables that need to be set for this class

Contract *pointer = &contract; //pointer
...
}
```

click buttons

```
void clickbutton(){
//clicking a button should change the contract values
pointer.firstvalue = 5;
}

void clickbutton2(){
//clicking a button should change the contract values
pointer.secondvalue = 10;
}
```

Edit: Alright, I see what I've done wrong. I was confused about declaring outside of main because I could not set the 'firstvalue' and 'secondvalue'. However I can set them in main and declare the variable outside of main. I won't be needing the pointer in that case. Thanks and sorry for the horrendous code that caused confusion.

Comment: Do you expect the `pointer` declared in `main` to be visible everywhere else in the program?

Comment: `Contract *contract;` declares an uninitialised pointer; you need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: Please, learn from a book.

Comment: There are so many errors in this code... I think you misunderstood how to declare a pointer and an automatic variable:
`Contract *contract` is a pointer.
`Contract pointer` is not.

Comment: Sorry about the Contract *contract, I fixed that, that wasn't in my code, I was typing this example up quickly and didn't realize I wrote that

Comment: @Chowza when you type an example, compile the example and make sure it has the same problems as your real code so we don't waste time correcting mistakes that aren't in your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare those variables outside of main(), if and only if the code for the buttons is in the same scope. Otherwise, declare them as static, but take a look on what it does.

Comment: Global variables lead to all sorts of design issues.  This is best to be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Okay. Now that you've fixed your original errors, the reason why your `clickbutton()` is producing an error is because the `pointer` variable is **not in scope**.

You will need something like the following:

```
void clickbutton(Contract *pointer){
  //clicking a button should change the contract values
  pointer->firstvalue = 5;
}
```

Alternatively, if your contract is a global object (always exists),

```
Contract *pointer;
void clickbutton() {
  pointer->firstvalue = 5;
}
int main() {
  Contract c;
  pointer = &c;
  clickbutton();
}
```

But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sorry about the Contract *contract, I fixed that, that wasn't in my code, I was typing this example up quickly and didn't realize I wrote the * in the wrong place. I fixed it to show what my code actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your functions so that they take the pointer you want to use as a parameter.  Sounds like you are going for a global variable, which should be avoided if possible.  Passing your objects around (like below) is a much better idea.  Note the use of the arrow `->` operator as opposed to the dot `.` operator since we are dealing with pointers.

```
void clickbutton(Contract *pointer) {
    //clicking a button should change the contract values
    pointer->firstvalue = 5;
}

void clickbutton2(Contract *pointer) {
    //clicking a button should change the contract values
    pointer->secondvalue = 10;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile, you are using `.` not `->` (We are assuming Contract contains a `firstvalue` member)

Comment: Yeah realized that right after I posted and fixed it.  Copy/paste!